# Best way to convert R data.table to pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, r, pandas, data.table

what would be the in your experience the best way to convert R data.table frame into a Pandas dataframe? I looked into different options, like hdf5 (3 libraries), rpy (does not seem to have this functionality?), and decided to ask the esteemed community: do you have any code snippets to do it the fastest, easiest, and the most reliable way?

R and python code snippets would be preferable.

Comment: `data.table::fwrite` and then read csv from pandas, it is extremely fast, at least the R part

Comment: Also see [feather](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/03/29/feather/).

Comment: @joran awww. That warms my heart!

Comment: Both feather and fwrite are fairly new, so check that their feature sets match your needs and/or you can take step necessary to use them. For example, with `fwrite`, dates are written as their numeric or integer codes by default. https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1664 If you need reliability and don't care about maintaining fancy attributes (like unobserved factor/categorical levels), just use the vanilla, well-established CSV tools on each end...

Comment: any examples with hdf5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for now the simplest and most reliable way to do so is via csv

R:

```
write.csv(df, file)
```

Python:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, na_values=['NA'])
```